# Proof with forall for a particular term

Tags: coq

I have a proof that states the following:

```
forall n:nat, 0 <= n -> My_Property.
```

If I want to prove it let's say for n=2. Is there a way to tell Coq that because 2 is of type `nat` greater than 0, that `2 -> My_Property` and that I can prove it for this particular case ?

Answer (score 1):

If your proof has a name, for example:

```
Lemma My_PropertyP : forall (n : nat), 0 <= n -> My_Property n.
```

you can refer to the case `n = 2` with `My_PropertyP 2`:

```
Check (My_PropertyP 2).
(*
My_PropertyP 2
     : 0 <= 2 -> My_Property 2
*)
```

And since indeed we can prove `0 <= 2`,

```
Lemma leq_0_2 : 0 <= 2. Proof. auto. Qed.
```

we can even instantiate this proof to obtain `My_Property 2`:

```
Check (My_PropertyP 2 leq_0_2).
(*
My_PropertyP 2 leq_0_2
     : My_Property 2
*)
```

The above illustrates that you can think of lemmas as functions. `name : forall (n : nat), P n` represents a function called `name` that receives an element `n` of type `nat` and outputs an element of type `P n`. If `P n` has type `Prop` we usually say that `name` is a "lemma" instead of a "function" and that `name n` is a "proof of `P n`" instead of an "element of type `P n`", but ultimately they are just different names for the same thing. This is related to the [Curry-Howard Isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

P.S. `0 <= n` holds for every natural number, so it is spurious in this particular example.

---

If your *goal* is to prove that for every `n` something holds, then showing the particular case `n = 2` won't solve the goal.

If you want to give a different proof for `n = 2` than for every other `n`, you have two options:

1. Case analysis on `n`.

```
  intro n.
  case n.
  - admit. (* 0 *)
  - intro n'; case n'.
    + admit. (* 1 *)
    + intro n''; case n''.
      * admit. (* 2 *)
      * admit. (* 3 <= n *)
```

2. Case analysis on whether `n` equals 2.

```
Require Import Arith.
(*...*)
intro n.
case (Nat.eq_dec n 2).
- (* n = 2 -> ... *)
  admit.
- (* n <> 2 -> ... *)
  admit.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If this appears in a sub goal, i.e I have a sub goal (1/1) of the form ```forall n:nat, 0 <= nat -> My_Property ``` how could I use it as you mentionned to prove for the particular case n = 2 ?

Comment: @MusherSoccoli: see my edit.